# Obtener valor al clickear un button y mostrarlo en un input text html5 y geolocalización de google maps

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, botón, geolocalización

buenos días los saludo.

Lo que pasa es que quiero obtener las coordenadas de google maps, clickeando un botón y que me aparezca la información en un archivo de texto tipo input.

Este es mi codigo:

```
function getLocation(){
if(navigator.geolocation){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("coord").innerHTML = "Ohhh! Lo Lamentamos."
    }
}

function showPosition(posicion){
    document.getElementById("coord").innerHTML=""+ posicion.coords.latitude + posicion.coords.longitude;
}
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" integrity="sha256-zgND4db0iXaO7v4CLBIYHGoIIudWI5hRMQrPB20j0Qw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick="getLocation()" class="localizar" title="Localizar"><img src="../imagenes/localizacion.png" alt="Icono localización" width="90%"></button>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lug_den" id="coord" placeholder="¿DONDÉ?" autocomplete="off" required maxlength="61">
```

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar, he estado mirando otros post y foros y no he encontrado la solución. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Farid, te recomiendo seguir el [tour] y leerte la guía sobre cómo preguntar que encontrarás en la sección ayuda para que tus mensajes sean de mayor calidad y obtener respuestas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @farid estas usando innerHTML en un input, así no funciona.
Si ya estás usando jquery puedes cambiar la función `showPosition()` asi:

```
function showPosition(posicion){
    $('#coord').val(posicion.coords.latitude +' : '+ posicion.coords.longitude);
}
```

el método `val()` de jquery actualiza el valor del input. Espero te sirva!

Comment: Ohh amigo, **Gracias** por su ayuda. me funcionó.